# Push a feature branch to develop branch using git

Tags: git, git-branch

Assume that I have two branches as the following: the blue branch is a main develop branch and the yellow branch is a new-feature branch.

[image]

At some point, I know I have enough feature in my new-feature branch and I wish I could use them in the main develop branch. However, the new-feature is not quite done yet and I still want to keep working on it. Is there a way to push the modifications in the new feature branch to the main develop branch without merging them?

Is it a good practice to do so? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `git merger --no-ff <branch-name>` should be the right way of doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're mixing up terms here. Pushing and merging are different things in git. You might want to look at chery-picking. This will let you "cherry pick" specific commits into your branch. Might be from the dev to the master branch.